# Formulário não chega ao banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Eu criei um formulário em HTML/PHP, conclui e resolvi conectar o formulário ao meu banco de dados pelo XAMPP e tudo rodou sem apresentar nenhum erro, até então tentei enviar um formulário e salvou o mesmo no BD, porem, nas outras tentativas não salvou mais nenhuma informação e também não apresenta nenhuma mensagem de erro sequer, o que pode ser?

Segue os códigos:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fleisch Berg Co.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trabalho.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="cabecalho">
            <h1><img src="img/logo.png"></h1>    
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav class="menu">

        <ul>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="fleisch.html">A&nbspFleish&nbspBerg&nbspCo.</a>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="#">Lançamentos</a>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="#">História</a>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="#">Loja&nbspVirtual</a>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="trabalho.html">Trabalhe&nbspconosco</a>
             <li id="lmenu"><a href="#">Contatos</a></li></li>     
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div id="noti">
        <h3>Trabalhe conosco:</h3>

        <form method="post" id="jobform" action="jobs.php">
           <fieldset id="job"><legend>Identificação pessoal</legend>

           <p>Nome completo: <input type="text" name="tnome" id="cnome" size="25" maxlength="25" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required></p>
           <p>Data de nascimento: <input type="date" name="tidade" id="cidade" required></p>
           <p>Telefone: <input type="text" name="ttel" id="ctel" size="7" maxlength="7" placeholder="Seu telefone aqui" required></p>
           <fieldset id="gene"><legend>Gênero</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="tsexo" id="cmasc" required value="homem">  
                <label for="cmasc">Masculino</label><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="tsexo" id="cfem" required value="mulher">
                <label for="cfem">Feminino</label>
           </fieldset>
           <p>Endereço: <input type="text" name="tend" id="cend" size="35" maxlength="35" placeholder="Endereço aqui" required></p>
           <p><label for="cesc">Grau de escolaridade:</label></p>
           <textarea name="tesc" id="cesc" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Escreva seus cursos aqui" required=""></textarea>
           <p><label for="cexp">Experiência profissional:</label></p>
           <textarea name="texp" id="cexp" cols="45" rows="10" placeholder="Fala aqui as suas experiências profissíonais" required=""></textarea>
           <p><label for="csobre">Fala um pouco sobre você:</label></p>
           <textarea name="tsobre" id="csobre" cols="45" rows="10" placeholder="Fala um pouco sobre você aqui" required=""></textarea>
           <p><label for="cvaga" required>Vaga desejada:</label>
            <select name="tvaga" id="cvagas" required="">
                <option selected>Escolha a vaga</option>
                <option>Diretor</option>
                <option>Encarregado</option>
                <option>Guarda</option>
                <option>Secretária</option>
                <option>Ajudante Geral</option>
                <option>Caminhoneiro (Fixo)</option>
                <option>Caminhoneiro (Temporário)</option>
            </select>
           </fieldset>

            <P>
                <INPUT type="reset"  name="tres" value="Limpar">
                <INPUT type="submit" name="tenv" value="Enviar">
            </P>

        </form>


    </div>

    <footer>
        <div id="rodape">
            <img id="icone" src="img/icone.png">
            <p id="copy">© Copyright 2000-2018 Fleisch Berg Company S.A.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP (Formulário):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fleisch Berg Co.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/trabalho.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php


            include_once ('connection/conexao.php');
            $nome = $_POST['tnome'];
            $nasc = $_POST['tidade'];
            $tel = $_POST['ttel'];
            $gen = $_POST['tsexo'];
            $end = $_POST['tend'];
            $esco = $_POST['tesc'];
            $exp = $_POST['texp'];
            $sobre = $_POST['tsobre'];
            $vaga = $_POST['tvaga'];

            $formulariojobs = "INSERT INTO formjobs (nome, nasc, tel, gen, ende, esco, exp, sobre, vaga) VALUES ('$nome', '$nasc', '$tel', '$gen', '$end', '$esco', '$exp', '$sobre', '$vaga', NOW())";
            $resultado_msg_contato = mysqli_query($conn, $formulariojobs);




        ?>
    <a href="trabalho.html">Voltar</a>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP (CONEXÃO):

```
<?php 
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "jobs";

    //criar a conexão

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);


?>
```

Comment: Quais os campos e tipos de campos da tabela? Observe a chave primária, se está auto incrementando os novos posts. Coloque "echo" para exibir os dados na tela ao postar, o erro pode ser antes de chegar ao banco, e neste caso você verá os dados que a página exibe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está especificando **9** campos para receberem as informações, porém você manda **10** informações:

```
$formulariojobs = "INSERT INTO formjobs (nome, nasc, tel, gen, ende, esco, exp, sobre, vaga) VALUES ('$nome', '$nasc', '$tel', '$gen', '$end', '$esco', '$exp', '$sobre', '$vaga', NOW())";
```

## Você está enviando:

1. '$nome'
2. '$nasc'
3. '$tel'
4. '$gen'
5. '$end'
6. '$esco'
7. '$exp'
8. '$sobre'
9. '$vaga'
10. ***NOW()***

## Mas você atribui esses valores apenas a:

1. nome
2. nasc
3. tel
4. gen
5. ende
6. esco
7. exp
8. sobre
9. vaga

Você precisa ter o mesmo número de atribuições e de parâmetros.

---

## @edit

Para corrigir seu outro problema, siga o seguinte procedimento:

1. Crie um novo campo na sua tabela do tipo inteiro. Pode nomeá-lo como quiser, mas chamarei de ´id´
2. Defina esse novo campo com "auto incremento" (auto increment) e como chave primária (primary key)
3. Salve  e tente novamente inserir registros no banco de dados.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer a conexão com meu banco, porem, agora só salva apenas 1 informação e depois torna a parar de salvar, sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Como assim só salva uma informação? Apenas salva uma das variáveis?

Comment: Não, eu respondi todo o formulário e foi certinho, todas as varáveis, mas se eu responder o formulário novamente não envia nada para o BD, permanece apenas um.

Comment: Essa seria uma resposta para uma outra pergunta, mas vou editar minha resposta com o  que quer